# description of the language accepted by S->SS|bS|a

Tags: context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I want to know what language is generated by this CFG

`S → SS | bS | a`

I have obtained some strings but cannot find a pattern

```
abbaaaa
aaaaaaa
ba
aaaaa
aaaaaaabaaaabbaa
babaaabaaaba
bbbababaababaa
baabaa
baa
aaaaaabbaaabbba
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This grammar does not generate epsilon;
- The minimum length string generated by `S` is `"a"`. Also last character generated by `S` is also `a`;
- `bS` means that **if** there is `b` in the string **then** after it there must be more characters (because the grammar does not generate epsilon). These characters could be more `b`, but eventually `a` must follow (as noted up). That is `n` times of `b`, where `n >= 0`;
- Because of `SS` the language allows repetitions (an infinite number of times (`k`)) of this zero or more `b` characters followed by one `a`.

The language L should be this (where Sigma is the alphabet):

[image: language L]

This could be written with regular expression like this:

[image: regex]

Comment: The language is produced by the regular expression `(a|b)*a`; I'd write the set simply as `{ ω a | ω ∈ Σ* }`. Not that yours is wrong, but all those subscripted exponents seem unnecessary.

Comment: It could be. I found it to be more detailed and more related to the explanations in the text. The shortest regular expression I think is `(b*a)+`.